# Ethereum Wallet turns white

Tags: wallets

I have Eth.Wallet 0.8.1 for Win 64 bit. I can see the correct balance for a moment, but then it turns white. The bar with Eth. Wallet, Accounts , Edit, View, Develop, Window is visible, but the rest of the window is white. I had the same issue with the previous version since the last week. It worked perfectly before.

My computer skills are really basic and I will be really grateful for a step by step solution without IT jargon.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lack of display usually means insufficient memory and/or computational resources. Have a look at what Task Manager is showing. Disable any costly processes and relaunch the wallet (check if you are not mining).

In addition to this you may [raise](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/Y410p-How-to-change-CPU-process-priority-in-Windows-8/ta-p/1216776) the priority of the wallet application. If this doesn't yield any results use an older, more stable [version](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) of the wallet, after you've backed up your private keys, of course.

Comment: Thanks Sebi, I've raised the priority, which resulted in fully visible screen with the correct balance. I have now a different issue as I can't access any of the options on the screen (Wallet, Send, Add account,...). Left click simply produces.. nothing. I will try am older version of the Wallet. Thanks!